# PHP OOP Code understanding

Tags: php

I have to understand a script to make some additions and I have some short questions.

There are these few lines:

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['DB'])){
    $DB = new System\Database\MySQL(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,DB_PORT);
}

new System\SessionHandler();
```

I don't understand which path System\Database\MySQL and System\ defines, because there are no folders with these names.

Comment: They're [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: Read about namespaces.

Comment: namespaces are the files which are used in the code, the below path is from one of the file mentioned in the namespaces.

Comment: `grep -R 'namespace System\\Database' your/app/root` might help to find the file that defines the `MySQL` class.

Answer (score 1):

As John and Elon are saying they are namescpaces. This is creating a new object MySQL with the parameters: Server, User, Password, Database and Port.

Answer (score 0):

`System\Database\MySQL` may not neccessary match the path actually. This is just namespace. It depends on autoloader implementation. But in your case it can absent and you should look for manual include/require somewhere else up in the code.